# Displays 'email sent' but nothing in my inbox. CodeIgniter and gmail

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, gmail

Please check my below code in order to send an email from my gmail account to the same gmail account. When I run it, it says Email sent. But I cannot find any such in my inbox. Can anyone suggest what the problem can be?

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'koolpraju@gmail.com',
        'smtp_password' => '****',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);


    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('koolpraju@gmail.com','Prajakta');
    $this->email->to('koolpraju@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('This is a test email');
    $this->email->message('It is working. Great!! yey');

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was sent successfully';

    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

I have Xampp running with Mercury and have set up Mercury S SMTP Server parameters. I really dont understand why the emails are not going through? Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Print the debug messages (print_debugger) to see if this helps you.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I tried with print_debugger. It just plainly displays a message
From: "Prajakta" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "koolpraju@gmail.com" 
X-Sender: koolpraju@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4fe88f845e878@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?This_is_a_test_email?=
It is working. Great!! yey

Comment: Mail are not usually sent from localhost when using SSL. Try to send from your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMail()
{
    $config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

        $message = '';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
      $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```